# Mod problems in VS2010

Tags: c++

there is a long long number 11111111111111111 , and a int number 99,
when I using mod operator that it suddenly change 99 to 0.

After this,it becomes 99 again.
this is my code :

```
    if(cur.sum % N == 0 && cur.sum > 0){
        printf("%I64d  %d  %d  %d",cur.sum,N,cur.sum%N,N);
        return cur.t;
    }
```

I never change the value of N beyond it except getting data.
![my ide is vs2010][1]

Comment: Either use `std::cout` for printing or retag question as `C` instead of `C++`.

Answer (score 1):

`cur.sum%N` is still a `long long` and needs to be `printf`ed with `%I64d` otherwise your first `%d` will print the first half of the `long long` value last `%d` will be printing the second half of the `long long` value*.

To fix it, change your printf:

```
printf("%I64d  %d  %I64d  %d",cur.sum,N,cur.sum%N,N);
```

or better yet, use the `<<` operator on C++ standard library streams which mean you don't need to specify format parameters.

Note*: First and second half of the value may be different on different machines depending on your computer's endianness.

Comment: Thank you for your answer . May I ask that why 111111111111111111 mod 99  equals to 0 ?

Comment: Because 111111111111111111 = 1122334455667789 * 99